# Attempting to modify Chrome extension to alter display color

Tags: google-chrome-extension, customization, trello

There is this awesome Trello card separator plugin [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-separator/hfojfmphbkncpnphjpnkefeobhamafap), but the color of the separators is silver, a difficult color for me to see. Therefore, I am interested in changing it. I am unable to figure out where in the files this value exists, however? I have downloaded the ZIP version of the extension and have been looking through the source, but cannot seem to find the specific lines I'm looking for. Help is appreciated. I think it should be an easy fix, if I could just locate the lines to be changed, haha. Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Judging by the extension's manifest it's `trelloscrum.css`. Usually you can inspect the element in devtools, see which rules are actually applied, select and copy some unique value, then look for it in the source files.

Comment: That’s an awesome idea, sir! I hadn’t thought of that; thanks for your help!